# Spring Webflux, Server Sent Events & Firefox

Tags: firefox, spring-webflux, server-sent-events

I'm trying to get server sent events to work with Mozilla Firefox. Given a Spring Boot webservice like

```
@GetMapping(path = "/timestamps", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<String> timestamps() {
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .map(sequence -> LocalTime.now().toString());
}
```

which works fine using Chrome browser or Edge (always latest versions). I can see an unfinished request in the network analyzer tab and every second a new timestamp is displayed.

However, when I use Firefox (84.0.2 or older), the request is also shown in the network tab but no response headers or streaming data is shown.
When I terminate the Spring backend, Firefox pops up a dialog to save a file with the contents of the request, which fails, because the backend is already terminated.

It seems to me that there is some kind of `flush()` missing on the backend side.

Can anyone confirm or deny such behaviour with FF, Spring Webflux & SSE?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. It was Sophos Antivirus Web Safety, which scanned and blocked http traffic. Switching to https - so Sophos cannot scan anymore - or disabling Web Safety solved the issue.